# How to check where the person is using gps. Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to make an app, that when you are at "NEW YORK airport, New York, NY, United States"
A sound start playing.
So i have a 2 questions:

1. How can i get an exactly location of the person?
2. How can i check if the person is at "NEW YORK airport, New York, NY, United States"?

I hope you could help me, and if you don't understand me please ask me.

Gaauwe

ps. I'm just started with developing android apps, so could you give me an example or a helpful website?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the coordinates:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Find the coordinates of New York airport and check these with the obtained location